# Update user with process progress from singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, singleton, instance, objective-c-blocks

I got the following method in a **singleton/shared instance** and would like update the user with the progress of fetching emails.

```
- (void)getAllImapEmailsForMailbox:(NSString *)mailbox completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSString *errorString, NSArray *emails))block
```

First I'm unlocking the API with a key, then I'm connecting to their IMAP server, then I'm logging in with their details, then I select a particular mailbox, then I loop through whole mailbox to download the messages.

So I would like to know how would I get these updates from a singleton method to my view controller displaying these messages in a UIAlertView for example.

eg. Connecting.. Logging in.. Selecting mailbox.. Downloading mail 1 of 69..

I'm currently only doing 1 message saying Downloading Emails, but it takes too long and don't want the user to think the app is hanging and not doing anything. This is what I'm doing:

```
UIAlertView *loadingView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Downloading Emails..." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];
[loadingView show];

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
    [self getAllEmailsForMailbox:@"Inbox"];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [loadingView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
    });
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: FYI - you may wish to consider using https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD instead of an alert view.

Comment: Yeah I don't really care what I use, just wanna know how I would pull this off from a Singleton to my current view controller?

Comment: Just post the different messages at the different times in your code. If you plan on using an alert view, you will need to dismiss the old one and show a new one each time.

Comment: I can "post" them through NSLog no problem, but I can't use UIAlertView or anything else from a singleton?

Comment: Sure you can. Why don't you think you can?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add another block param called something like statusBlock.  Give the block a string param that will contain a status message.  How you get the status to send this block depends on the details of how you do the listed steps, but at an outline level...

```
- (void)getAllImapEmailsForMailbox:(NSString *)mailbox
      statusBlock:(void (^)(NSString *)statusBlock
      completionBlock:(void (^)(BOOL success, NSString *errorString, NSArray *emails))block {

    statusBlock(@"connecting");
    // do connecting stuff

    NSInteger numberOfMessagesToFetch = // find this out however you do now

    statusBlock([NSString stringWithFormat:@"fetching %d messages", numberOfMessagesToFetch]);

    // fetch mail, and so on
```

On the caller side:

```
[mailSingleton getAllImapEmailsForMailbox:@"mailbox"
    statusBlock:^(NSString *message) { // update UI with message }
    completionBlock: ... { // update UI now that you're complete }];
```

Also , looking at your edit, is it possible to hide the asynch stuff in this method?  Would be a lot friendlier for the caller, who could just pass the blocks and assume the asynch.

Comment: This worked, I thought it will stop the block, thanks, will be using in future ;)